Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module not supported when using mdxeditor and several React components
I am building a remix-run application wherein I want to use a react markdown editor component, such as mdx-editor in a one of my routes. When I insert this editor in my application
<MDXEditor markdown={'# Hello World'}/>

I get the following error:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module node_modules/@mdxeditor/editor/dist/index.js from /build/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of /node_modules/@mdxeditor/editor/dist/index.js in /build/index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (build/index.js:13135:21)

Now this is not the first time I have encountered this error in my project. I faced this same problem with react-markdown (which I solved by downgrading to one of its earlier release) and react-tag-input (which I solved by using some other similar react component). This time however I want to understand what am I doing wrong? Why did using an earlier release didn't produce this error that one time with react-markdown? What should I do to resolve this error?
What I have done so far:

I have followed this moving from CommonJS to ESM guide, which gave me this error.

[Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /mocks/index.js not supported. Instead change the require of index.js in null to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.] {code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'} Node.js v22.3.0


I have put type:module in my package.json (this is suggested in most of the answers on SO related to this error) which gives me this error.

Error: Error loading Remix config at /remix.config.js

ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and /package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.

I also renamed it to '.cjs' file extension but that gave another error.

I have looked into the issues of these repos (the ones which gave me this same error), but none of the issues are even remotely related to this [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM] error, which compels me to think that the issue is not with those repos, rather I am doing something very basic related to web dev in general very wrong. Simply doing what the thrown error says is not solving the issue and not increasing my understanding.

Some details:

remix-run version : 2.10.0

mdxeditor/editor: 3.10.0

node version - 22.3.0


